# Non-clustered index with INCLUDE equivalent in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I created a non-clustered index (using the execution plan tools in MSSQLSMS) that greatly speeds up a critical, time-consuming query. My test machine uses SQL Express 2008, but I'm limited to SQL Server 2000 on the production server.

The index includes some non-key columns in an `INCLUDE` statement:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxTotalFundsUnderManagementQuery_TotalPv
ON PortfolioMovements (PortfolioMovementType, AtDate)
INCLUDE (PortfolioID, SecurityGuid, Units)
```

`INCLUDE` isn't supported on SQL Server 2000. Is there a way to include non-key columns in the index?

Comment: The only option in SQL Server 2000 (yikes!) is to add those columns to your index. This however will bloat your index, and might have negative impact on your query performance.

Comment: You might also consider an indexed view with a similar sort of definition. Not as good an option as an NCI with `INCLUDE` however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258260(v=sql.80).aspx
It's a performance feature that was introduced in SS 2005 AFAIK.